# not counting grid rows on button click

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to count grid rows when i click button.

But it is counting grid rows on first click only.

When control goes on else, it not come out of it.

Here is my code-

dafault.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EmailExpenseByDay.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmailExpenseByDay" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <h3>Email Expenses by Date</h3>
    <table align="center" border="1">

        <tr>
            <td>Select Date:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td style="border:0">
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Select Valid Date" ControlToValidate="txtDate" Display="Dynamic" 
                    ForeColor="Red" 
                    ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{1,2})[./-]+([0-9]{1,2})[./-]+([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                     ErrorMessage="Select Date" ControlToValidate="txtDate" Display="Dynamic" 
                    ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Button ID="btnGenerateFile" runat="server" Text="Generate File" 
                    onclick="btnGenerateFile_Click"/></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="btnEmailFile" runat="server" OnClick="btnEmailFile_Click" Text="Email File" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" align="center" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Expense_Category" HeaderText="Expense_Category" 
                SortExpression="Expense_Category" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Expense_Description" 
                HeaderText="Expense_Description" SortExpression="Expense_Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
                SortExpression="Amount" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testAzharConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [Expense_Category], [Expense_Description], [Amount] FROM [CompanyExpenses3] WHERE ([Expense_Date] = @Expense_Date)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDate" DbType="Date" Name="Expense_Date" 
                PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <center>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold"></asp:Label>
    </center>
    <table align="center" id="table1" runat="server" border="1">
               <tr>
                   <td align="right">From:</td>
                   <td align="left"><asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                   <td style="border:0">
                       <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtFrom"
                        ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="Email Id is not Valid"   
                        Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td align="right">To:</td>
                   <td align="left"><asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                   <td style="border:0">
                       <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ControlToValidate="txtTo"  
                        ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="Email Id is not Valid"    
                        Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td align="right">Subject</td>
                   <td align="left"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td align="right">Attachment</td>
                   <td align="left"><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td align="center" colspan="2"><asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" onclick="btnSend_Click" Text="Send" /></td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 702px; top: 36px; position: absolute; width: 104px" Text=""></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Mail;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

public partial class EmailExpenseByDay : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.Visible = false;
        table1.Visible = false;


    }
    protected void btnGenerateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Page.IsValid)
        {

            if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.Visible = true;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; FileName=ExpenseReport.xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
                new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
                GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
                Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
                Response.End();
                Label1.Text = "File Generated";
            }   
            else{

                Label1.Text="No Expenses on this day";
            }
        }
    }
    protected void btnEmailFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table1.Visible = true;

    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */

    }
    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
        msg.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
        msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            String FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            // MailAttachment mailAttachment = new MailAttachment(FileName, MailEncoding.Base64);
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment mailAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream,FileName);
            msg.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
        }

        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtFrom.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Send(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added all of my code.

Please give me any suggestion how to do this this.

Comment: add the code where you are binding the gridView

Comment: i am getting data on grid from datasource.

Comment: your code seems ok, i think the problem might be resetting txtDate somewhere, can you see the Grid for 2nd, 3rd time of rendering the page after postback

Comment: @Manish-- I edited my question, added gridview code.

Comment: I've checked it and it seems ok to me. Add a button to the page (which do nothing). Just click this button multiple time and see if after each postback, the grid is shown on the page or does it disappears after 1st or 2nd click

Comment: I am not showing grid on click. I am generating excel file when there is a data in grid otherwise show on label that no data in grid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51646/discussion-between-manish-dalal-and-azhar-shahid)

Answer (score 1):

there is no problem with your code. It is actually when the data is getting bound to the gridView.

I found that while using `SqlDataSource` (or any other DataSource), the dataBinding is happening after `OnPreRender` (but before `OnPreRenderComplete`). So, if you wish to use the data in the GridView, you have to write your code in `OnPreRenderComplete`, or bind the data in `Page_Load` using `GridView1.DataBind()`

Finally, found the culprit...phew!

**To save the GridView as file**

```
  System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
  System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
  new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
  GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
  string gvHtml = stringWrite.ToString();

  File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/yourSubFolder/") + fileName, gvHtml);

  string urlOfFile = "/yourSubFolder/" + fileName;
```

---

*Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.*

Comment: On doing this, file is generating but why my label text not changed. How can I show either file is generated or not.

Comment: When you are generating the file, the file is getting downloaded and the page is not getting refreshed, hence your label do not change. A workaround could be.... on button click, create the file and save it on server, update the label and provide a hyperlink to download the file

Comment: how can file generate without going into if block..?

Comment: updated the answer. you will have to go to if block, but not send the file back in response. Instead save the file on server